# Recovery of audit trail in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, database-administration, rman

If Audit_trail parameter is enabled and location of the auditing has been set to a different tablespace which was manually created. someone mistakenly dropped that tablespace. Is there any way to recreate the db objects like aud$ table etc.?

Recovery of audit data is not that important but can we recover the db object which we lost while dropping that table space?

I found the script of recreating the table aud$ but I am not sure if we have lost some other db objects at that time about which I am not aware and may have a impact later.

In short I am not confident.

We are taking differential backup on routine basis and archive log backup in every 3 hours

Comment: "We are taking differential backup on routine basis and archive log backup in every 3 hours" - so you should have a copy of it in your backups, no?

Comment: I have but I never recovered audit data specifically, that's why seeking help.